# Prove the limiting case of a modified Bessel Function of the first kind as $x \to 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, bessel-functions

> Prove: $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{J_1(x)}{x}=\frac{1}{2}$

I found it to be $\frac{1}{3}$, not $\frac{1}{2}$.

**My attempt:**

I used this formula as an approximation (from hyperphysics)

[image]

Therefore,

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{J_1(x)}{x}= \frac{\frac{(x)^1}{1 \cdot 3}}{x} = \frac{1}{3}$$

I'm guessing my error is in using an approximation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bessel function of the first kind, order $1$ is denoted $J_1$ (i.e., upper case $J$) while the ***spherical*** Bessel function of the first kind, order $1$ is denoted $j_1$ (i.e., lower case $j$).

The Taylor series for $J_1(x)$ is given by

$$J_1(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)!}\left(\frac x2\right)^{2n+1}$$

which has leading term $x/2$.  Therefore, $\frac{J_1(x)}{x}\sim \frac12$ as $x\to 0$.

The spherical Bessel function, $j_1$, is given by $j_1(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}-\frac{\cos(x)}{x}$.  Noting the

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}-\frac{\cos(x)}{x}}{x}=\frac13$$

we see that $\frac{j_1(x)}{x}\sim \frac13$ for $x\to 0$.